# Custom open/close Drawer animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have Drawer navigator inside my app. I've successfully changed the default (right to left) animation between screens to fadeIn/fadeOut.

But I can't find a way to change the default animation for react-navigation Drawer that slides from right to left. I need it to fadeIn/fadeOut instead.

I'm using custom drawer component and `navigation.openDrawer()` to open and `navigation.closeDrawer()` to close the drawer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is broad and general -- could you please make it more specific by adding details, including any code you have written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the drawer animation to something different, but **not** to a `fade` Animation.

```
drawerType - Type of the drawer. It determines how the drawer looks and animates.

- front: Traditional drawer which covers the screen with a overlay behind it.
- back: The drawer is revealed behind the screen on swipe.
- slide: Both the screen and the drawer slide on swipe to reveal the drawer.
```

Alternatively you can animate the content inside the drawer:

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => {
  const translateX = props.drawerOpenProgress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-100, 0],
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
      {/* ... drawer contents */}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it using drawerOpenProgress and interpolate function.

Comment: @moritzw props.drawerOpenProgress is undefined? Can you provide your code sample??

Comment: drawerContent are missing a property progress

@react-navigation/native - 6.0.2
@react-navigation/drawer - 6.1.4